# Rendering a hash in a Rails View

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a hash like this

```
valuehash={:a => { "test1"=>"testing1"} , :b => {"test2" => "testing2"}}
```

I want my response as below

```
value : [ { "test1" :"testing1"} ,
        {"test2" : "testing2"}]
```

I have tried below code in my View but it doesn't seem to work

```
json.value do
  json.child! do
    json.template! valuehash[:a]
  end
  json.child! do
    json.template! valuehash[:b]
  end
end
```

Can any one tell me what is the problem with my code .Also to need I need to do some modification to value hash based on some conditions so I don't want to use map,select but want to use something like above to render.

Comment: What ouput are you getting now? How is it not working?

Comment: I am getting the output as    value : [ "template!" :{"test1" : "testing1"},"template!":"test2" : "testing2"] . I want the output as value : [{"test1" : "testing1"} , {"test2" : "testing2"}] with some modifications based on some conditions.

Comment: if that is still a Hash you can `hash.values` but I guess it is a string. I would go for manipulating the Hash directly rather than using templates. Seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
valuehash={:a => { "test1"=>"testing1"} , :b => {"test2" => "testing2"}}
# {:a=>{"test1"=>"testing1"}, :b=>{"test2"=>"testing2"}} 
value = valuehash.map { |_,val| val }
# [{"test1"=>"testing1"}, {"test2"=>"testing2"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment ,but is there any way I can achieve the same using json.child! in my view. I actually want to modify some values in valuehash so thats why I want to use json.child!

Comment: so you want the response as a json string - not as an array of hashes?